# In a windows service, will OnStop run if the OnStart is blocked?

Tags: c#, windows-services

If my OnStart method is

```
while (true)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Will OnStop run in this case? Or do I have to create a new thread such that the thread OnStart is running on unblocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thread that calls `OnStart` doesn't "belong" to you. You're not **meant** to block it. You should use it to set up any threads, any timers, any listeners on the network, etc, and then *return* from the `OnStart` method.

Only when you *return* from `OnStart` will the service control manager transition your service from `Starting` to `Started`.